# Unusual datetime behavior in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to generate the day of time stamps recorded in the UTC time zone, using `as.Date()`. This sometimes produces inexplicable NA's in a grouped tbl_df object, though not if I enclose that same object in `data.frame()`, `ungroup()`, or filter it. My example is below. The grouped tbl_df object is `checkit` and the errant observation is #3, for wcid = 148. There is nothing unusual about its timestamp, yet `as.Date()` will return a `NA` for it, unless I transform `checkit` as described above:

```
> checkit
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: wcid, ab_split_test [6]

   wcid ab_split_test   mailing_timestamp
  (dbl)         (chr)              (time)
1     1             N                <NA>
2    78             Y 2016-04-04 12:28:58
3   148             Y 2016-03-17 09:11:31
4   204             Y 2016-03-04 09:01:15
5   255             Y 2016-03-03 09:18:43
6   267             Y 2016-03-23 09:16:50
> class(checkit)
[1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> checkit %>% mutate(treatment_day_actual = as.Date(mailing_timestamp))
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: wcid, ab_split_test [6]

   wcid ab_split_test   mailing_timestamp treatment_day_actual
  (dbl)         (chr)              (time)               (date)
1     1             N                <NA>                 <NA>
2    78             Y 2016-04-04 12:28:58           2016-04-04
3   148             Y 2016-03-17 09:11:31                 <NA>
4   204             Y 2016-03-04 09:01:15           2016-03-04
5   255             Y 2016-03-03 09:18:43           2016-03-03
6   267             Y 2016-03-23 09:16:50           2016-03-23
> ungroup(checkit) %>% mutate(treatment_day_actual = as.Date(mailing_timestamp))
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]

   wcid ab_split_test   mailing_timestamp treatment_day_actual
  (dbl)         (chr)              (time)               (date)
1     1             N                <NA>                 <NA>
2    78             Y 2016-04-04 12:28:58           2016-04-04
3   148             Y 2016-03-17 09:11:31           2016-03-17
4   204             Y 2016-03-04 09:01:15           2016-03-04
5   255             Y 2016-03-03 09:18:43           2016-03-03
6   267             Y 2016-03-23 09:16:50           2016-03-23
> data.frame(checkit) %>% mutate(treatment_day_actual = as.Date(mailing_timestamp))
  wcid ab_split_test   mailing_timestamp treatment_day_actual
1    1             N                <NA>                 <NA>
2   78             Y 2016-04-04 12:28:58           2016-04-04
3  148             Y 2016-03-17 09:11:31           2016-03-17
4  204             Y 2016-03-04 09:01:15           2016-03-04
5  255             Y 2016-03-03 09:18:43           2016-03-03
6  267             Y 2016-03-23 09:16:50           2016-03-23
> filter(checkit, wcid == 148) %>% mutate(treatment_day_actual = as.Date(mailing_timestamp))
Source: local data frame [1 x 4]
Groups: wcid, ab_split_test [1]

   wcid ab_split_test   mailing_timestamp treatment_day_actual
  (dbl)         (chr)              (time)               (date)
1   148             Y 2016-03-17 09:11:31           2016-03-17
```

And here's dput:

```
> dput(checkit)
structure(list(wcid = c(1, 78, 148, 204, 255, 267), ab_split_test = c("N", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"), mailing_timestamp = structure(c(NA, 
1459787338.92449, 1458220291.82732, 1457100075.70328, 1457014723.60799, 
1458739010.74587), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), vars = list(
    wcid, ab_split_test), drop = TRUE, indices = list(0L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
    wcid = c(1, 78, 148, 204, 255, 267), ab_split_test = c("N", 
    "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), vars = list(wcid, ab_split_test), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("wcid", 
"ab_split_test")), .Names = c("wcid", "ab_split_test", "mailing_timestamp"
))
```

I just noticed from `dput()` that the time zone is missing. When I query it it shows up as my locale:

```
> attr(as.POSIXlt(checkit$mailing_timestamp),'tzone')
[1] ""    "EST" "EDT"
```

This is not as it should be either, because the sql argument in my `dplyr::tbl()` call specifically requested UTC, as in `select mailing_timestamp at time zone 'UTC' as mailing_timestamp`. I am connecting to a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: I can't reproduce with *dplyr_0.4.3.9001*.  I know there were some issues with `mutate` and groups and `NA` in dplyr 0.4.3 that have been fixed in the [development version](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr).

Comment: Can you provide a few rows of your data using `dput` (i.e. `dput(checkit)`).

Comment: I'm nervous about using the development version of `dplyr`. I used to be able to check whether a SQL query `foo` returned a null object with the condition `nrow(compute(foo)) == 0`, before running `collect(foo)`. That feature seems broken in the development version. I doubt it's gone forever, so for now I'll just `ungroup()` to get the correct `as.Date()` response, and keep my other code working.